fastify websocket and socketio
i am wroking on a project using fastify
and i am using @fastify/websocket to handle socket connections
and we did merge some parts with another proeject which is using fastify-socket.io
and both libs have some conflicts
when i tried to run socket.io
im not able to connect to it but still table to connect to websocket
  app.register(import('@fastify/websocket'));
  app.register(import('fastify-socket.io'), {
    cors: {
      origin: '*',
      methods: ['GET', 'POST'],
    },
    transports: ['websocket'],
  });

and im trying to make them work together instead of transforming all the websocket to socketio or socketio to websocket
